# issues with circular queues

Tags: queue, stack, circular-dependency

I'm trying to create a circular queue class and i seem to be indexing incorrectly. Any tips on how to fix the issues im running into ?

class circularQueue(ShufflingQueue):
def **init**(self,capacity):
super().**init**(capacity)
def is_empty(self):
super().is_empty()
def is_full(self):
super().is_full()

```
def enqueue(self,item):
    if self.is_full() == True:
        raise FullError("the queue is full")
    elif self.is_empty():
        self.front = self.front = 0
        self.rear = self.rear = 0 
        self.queue[self.rear] = item
        
    else:
        self.rear =(self.rear+1) % self.capacity
        self.queue[self.rear] = item

def dequeue(self):
   if self.is_empty()== True:
        raise IndexError("cannot dequeu an empty queue")
   else:
       temp = self.queue[self.front]
       self.front = (self.front+1) % self.capacity
       return temp
```

i was expecting this to add some values to the queue using the enqueue method. havennt evven gotten to see if the logic works for dequeue yet.